# Mutate method not applicable for date columns in R

Tags: r, excel, list, date, dplyr

I am trying to convert data class from excel numeric to date (as R imports from excel date cols as numeric),
I am doing this for date columns in a df contained in a list of dataframes,

However when mutate function is run it says it is not applicable for objects of class "Date"

Here's the code:

```
# inspecting first 4 date column elements from df contained in list #
                                 ))
for(i in 1:length(df_list[["df1"]][["col_date"]])){
  if(i < 5L){
     print(head(df_list[["df1"]][["col_date"]][[i]], n= 5L))
  } else {
     break
  }
}

// console output //

[1] "33634"
[1] "32242"
[1] "25491"
[1] "34919"

# defining date columns #
col_dates <- c("col_date1", "col_date2", "col_date3")

# converting to date #
df_list[["df1"]] <- df_list[["df1"]] %>%
                                 dplyr :: 
                                 mutate(
                                 excel_numeric_to_date(
                                 as.numeric(
                                 as.character(
                                 date_columns)),
                                 date_system = "modern"
                                 ))

// console output //

Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "Date"
Además: Warning message:
In excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(as.character(date_columns)),  :
  NAs introducidos por coerción
```

Is there any other way to apply this function to df cols in a list?

Comment: If you're using `<-` assignment, you can do it in a base R fashion like `df_list[["df1"]][date_columns] <- lapply(df_list[["df1"]][date_columns], f)` where `f` is a predefined function like `f <- function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))`

Comment: @TTS, already edited the above code

Comment: I think TTS meant providing an example of `df_list`, maybe something like `df_list <- list(df1 = data.frame(a=1:3,date1=33634+0:2, date2=33634+0:2, date3=33634+0:2))` ?